# QuantLib option.NPV() returns interpolation error

Tags: programming, quantlib

I've been trying to price some barrier options with a Heston model on Quantlib and it works quite well most of the times, but sometimes I get the error: "interpolation range is [3.4314, 4.28384] x [0, 1.07814]: extrapolation at (3.30138, 0.0939798) not allowed". Is anyone familiar with this issue? I tried to do it with hard numbers instead of through variables, but it still doesn't seem to work. The option that generates this error is a barrier down and in put option on 'POST.VI', with strike 38.65, barrier 80%, maturity date 2022-12-22

Thanks

I use the exact same code as shown in the documentation, but in case anyone wants to see it:

```
today = ql.Date().todaysDate()
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today
maturity = ql.Date(maturity_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
riskfree = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
    ql.FlatForward(today, riskFreeRate, ql.Actual365Fixed())
)
dividend = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
    ql.FlatForward(today, dividendYield, ql.Actual365Fixed())
)

option = ql.BarrierOption(
    ql.Barrier.DownIn,
    strike * barrier,
    0,
    ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(ql.Option.Put, strike),
    ql.EuropeanExercise(maturity)
)

hestonprocess = ql.HestonProcess(
    riskfree, dividend, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(spot)), *heston_parameter
)
hestonmodel = ql.HestonModel(hestonprocess)
engine = ql.FdHestonBarrierEngine(hestonmodel)
option.setPricingEngine(engine)
option.NPV()
```

**Edit**
I noticed that this error occurs exactly when the barriers are broken.